# Changing variables in a gulp file

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, hygieia

There is an application that runs with
gulp file - https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia/blob/master/UI/gulpfile.js

A config array is present in which there are module, local, api variables. refresh

By default `**config.api** == null`
As far as I understand, when running gulp (or maybe when building), we can somehow assign the value we need there.

How to do this, can you please point me in the right direction?